# CLLocationManager Simulator to simulate car moves?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, gps, kml, core-location

I'm looking since quite a long time something like a `CLLocationManager` simulator that would enable me to simulate GPS positions (`CLLocation` instances that could be retrieved through the `CLLocationManager` standard delegate mechanism) along a predefined route for instance (with a [KML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keyhole_Markup_Language) or [GPX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GPS_eXchange_Format) file 
as input,  or whatever, but KML would be nice ;).

Something like this is available on the Android emulator and I was wondering if anything like this would exist for the iPhone simulator.
At least this would be great and would speed up testing on the simulator instead of having to drive for real.... :/

If nothing like this exists, what would be your approach to fake such behavior and implement the simulator in such a way that the client is not impacted? (No code change in the delegate of the `CLLocationManager` for instance.)

Thanks for your links, hints, approaches...

Comment: I have just the same issue and so have spent time researching this issue.  AFAIK, the iPhone simulator cannot be injected like android's.  So, the currently suggested method is to read a file with lat/lon/alt/etc., and post those messages to the didReceiveLocationUpdate (IIRC) method.

Comment: Yes this was also my "desperate" solution :) But isn't there any open source project that would generate the didReceiveLocation at the appropriate rate for instance ? Or better, if you have recorded some gpx trace, would take into account the timestamps to reproduce the same scenario ? I've looked for such a thing but didn't manage to get one ? :O If I don't get any link for that I think I will start my own project around this.. :/ (or wait for SDK 4.0 ? ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best approach is to take control from the CLLocationManager by implementing your own category for it and simulate your expected behavior.

I put a description of this approach here : 
[Testing CoreLocation on iPhone Simulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/802156/testing-corelocation-on-iphone-simulator/2060315#2060315)

Answer (score 1):

You can't inject the simulator, but you can subclass CoreLocation:

http://code.google.com/p/dlocation/

which subclasses CoreLocationDelegate to return real data on a device and data from a text file when on the simulator.

More info here

[Testing CoreLocation on iPhone Simulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/802156/testing-corelocation-on-iphone-simulator)

HTH

Comment: I took a look at the approach in the project you refered to, but I think I found better than subclassing ;) My answer here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/802156/testing-corelocation-on-iphone-simulator/2060315#2060315