# Debugging CoreLocation app in real IOs device

Tags: iphone, ios, gps, core-location

I'm developing an application that uses CoreLocation Framework to track user movements. I'm caching the information into a DB to make use of it later, etc. The problem I'm facing is that this kind of application is not to be tested on the Simulator, but on a real device with real data, but I don't find a way to at least access the data my application is generating and storing into its DB. I'd like to know some tips or hints related to the way of testing&debugging this kind of application.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to access the application's data you can follow the steps on this [post](http://losingfight.com/blog/2008/08/15/how-to-get-application-data-from-the-iphone/). If you are using an SQLite database, I'd suggest you to use the SQLite Manager plugin for Firefox, it works great.

I hope it helps

Cheers!

Comment: @Yuchen Fixed. It might be outdated, though.

Answer (score 0):

You need to [adopt](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManagerDelegate_Protocol/CLLocationManagerDelegate/CLLocationManagerDelegate.html) locationManager:didUpdateToLocation:fromLocation: of CLLocationManagerDelegate. You will receive newLocation in this callback.
newLocation.coordinate - that's what you need.

Answer (score 0):

You can test on the iPhone simulator using a CLLocationManager simulator and that way you'll have access to the data in your DB.  There are several CLLocationManager simulators out there that run on the iPhone simulator [see this answer on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2841140/core-location-in-iphone-simulator-3-2-ipad/2842131#2842131).