# userLocation: latitude/longitude return zero?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I am just looking at mapKit and decided to make a quick button to display my current location, however when I press the button my latitude/longitude always display as [0.000000] [0.000000].

The mapView is loaded as I can see the map on the simulator before I press the button. Previously I have done this by using coreLocation.framework and using CLLocationManager and asking for the device location that way. I am just curious why this way is not working correctly, would I be better doing this via CLLocationManager?

```
-(IBAction)findMePressed {
    MKUserLocation *myLocation = [myMapView userLocation];
    CLLocationCoordinate2D coord = [[myLocation location] coordinate];
    [myMapView setCenterCoordinate:coord animated:YES];
    NSLog(@"findMePressed ...[%f][%f]", coord.latitude, coord.longitude);
}
```

EDIT: Added ...

```
-(IBAction)findMePressed {
     MKUserLocation *myLocation = [myMapView userLocation];
     CLLocationCoordinate2D coord = [[myLocation location] coordinate];
     MKCoordinateRegion region = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(coord, 350, 350);
     [myMapView setRegion:region animated:YES];
}

-(void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [myMapView setShowsUserLocation:YES];
}
```

Gary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either the userLocation is not visible on the map (see the [userLocationVisible](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKMapView_Class/MKMapView/MKMapView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008205-CH3-SW16) property) or there is some problem setting up the myMapView property and it's nil (i.e. not connected in interface builder)

Comment: Hi Dean, userLocationVisible is [0] so I guess that is the problem. myMapView is connected in IB so its correctly pointing to my iVar.

Comment: The way my map was displaying Cupertino was just off the left of the display. Setting showUserLocation and making a region did what I was expecting, much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

> [...] as I can see the map on the *simulator* [...]

Test it on the device. By default, on the simulator, the coordinates you get back are Apple's headquarters. Cf. [doc](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/xcode/conceptual/iphone_development/125-Using_iPhone_Simulator/iphone_simulator_application.html).

See this other SO question for workarounds and useful utilities : [Testing CoreLocation on iPhone Simulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/802156/testing-corelocation-on-iphone-simulator)