# MKMapView getting current location

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios6, mapkit

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [userLocation: latitude/longitude return zero?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3178965/userlocation-latitude-longitude-return-zero)

I am trying to get the current location of `MKMapView` for that I added

```
CLLocationCoordinate2D coordiante = self.mapView.userLocation.location.coordinate;      
NSLog(@"%f %f",coordiante.latitude,coordiante.longitude);
```

to my `viewDidLoad` method.
But the lattitude and longitude values i am getting as 0.00000

Here is the output of console.

```
2013-01-07 18:41:26.349 MapKitExample[4623:c07] 0.000000 0.000000
```

Comment: @dandan78 -yes..i did that

Comment: change the method to viewwillappear

Comment: even then the output is same..

Comment: please check the answer on this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3178965/userlocation-latitude-longitude-return-zero