# why does didUpdateToLocation method not getting called on ios4?

Tags: iphone

Can anyone plz tell me why didUpdateToLocation method is not getting called on ios4 whereas it is getting called on ios3?

Ragards,
Vikas

Answer (score 2):

For iOS 4.1 Simulator, You need to use the CoreLocation Simulator - see at [Testing CoreLocation on iPhone Simulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/802156/testing-corelocation-on-iphone-simulator)