# Does speed display work on IOS Simulator?

Tags: iphone, performance, ios, core-location, simulator

We are having issue with displaying Speed which is part of Description that comes with CoreLocation working on Ios Simulator for Iphone. In the view controller, we connect the Description to label. It does display most of information such as lat and long, time. We can verify that the lat and long, and time displayed change when we move from one location to another. However, the speed is either -1 (when we are not moving) or 0 (when we are moving).

How we test it？ We use ios simulator that comes with XCODE 4 and connect to 3G internet connection and drive around the town. We can also verify that the information displayed refreshes every minute.

Questions:
- does Ios Simulator support the Speed display from CoreLocation?
- does corelocation work only on certain type of internet connection? wifi, airport?
- do we have to deploy the app into iphone to get Speed displayed properly?

Answer (score 0):

try this answers

[Testing CoreLocation on iPhone Simulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/802156/testing-corelocation-on-iphone-simulator)

Comment: Thanks for the response. We had a look at the link you provided. Our situation is different. We use Iphone Simulator built-in Xcode 4. The post also mentioned lat long not displaying properly. We have got lat long displayed, but the Speed property is always displaying -1 or 0.

Comment: it's strange to me that IOS simulator shows your actual coordinates. My simulator in Xcode still shows me Infinite Loop 1 only - Apple HQ