# Core location not showing location on ios simulator 4.3

Tags: iphone, ios-simulator, ipod-touch

I search core location in my x-code 4.3 for an example. I found LocateMe and Location examples but they are not showing any location on simulator. then i develop my own application this one is also unable to show any location. it throws error time out after time out interval. so

Comment: i dont think that simulator will give you location ...use it on the device ...and it will work gud im sure...!!!

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/802156/testing-corelocation-on-iphone-simulator

Comment: no it should give apple headquarter location coordinates. i used to check location of apple headquarter loation coordinates on xcode 3.1.2

Comment: Later versions added supported for giving an accurate(ish) location, presumably using WiFi positoning

Comment: u means the simulator can give my location using internet(something)

Answer (score 0):

Enable WiFi on your computer if you have it.  That usually does it for me.

Comment: i am using mac book pro and airport is enable