# How to solve Xcode 4.1 (LION) GPS error?

Tags: iphone, core-location, osx-lion, xcode4.1

My project worked perfectly on simulator+device,
but now, after upgrading to **lion** os and **xcode 4.1**, I get this error when gps is active!

```
server did not accept client registration 68
```

It's a gps based application, and i'm nervous to not debug app in simulator!

Any idea to solve this issue?

---

**UPDATE**: Gps on Simulator doesn't work also on Xcode 3.2.6 + LION.

---

**EDIT**: Apple response on bug tracker:

> After further investigation it has
>   been determined that this is a known issue, which is currently being
>   investigated by engineering. This issue has been filed in our bug
>   database under the original Bug ID#.   Thank you for submitting this
>   bug report. We truly appreciate your assistance in helping us discover
>   and isolate bugs.

Comment: Having the same issue, error code and all.  Lion seems to have new location services preferences in Security & Privacy settings, under "Privacy" tab, and iOS Simulator doesn't show up in the list of apps at all.  There doesn't seem to be a way to manually add it, either.

Comment: They are working in iOS Simulator 5.0

Comment: I recommend you open a bug to Apple.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Xcode 4.2 solved this problem adding custom gps position!

The file is an XML like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<gpx version="1.1" creator="Xcode"> 
  <wpt lat="45,49939" lon="9,12114">
    <name>Milano</name>
  </wpt>
</gpx>
```

you can add this file in your project or New->File->GPX.

While you're running your app, activate the console and select your custom position file:

[image]

it's all.
enjoy.

Comment: This only works if you're debugging against iOS 5. If you use the 4.3 simulator, there's no loc icon.

Comment: Wow, i was wondering how to make this file since a long time ago !

Answer (score 2):

From the Big Nerd Ranch forum:

```
@implementation CLLocationManager (TemporaryHack)
- (void)hackLocationFix {
    CLLocation *location = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:42 longitude:-50];
    [[self delegate] locationManager:self didUpdateToLocation:location fromLocation:nil];     
}
- (void)hackHeadingFix {
    [[self delegate] locationManager:self didUpdateHeading:(id)@"That way.."];
}
- (void)startUpdatingLocation {
    [self performSelector:@selector(hackLocationFix) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.1];
}
- (void)startUpdatingHeading {
    [self performSelector:@selector(hackHeadingFix) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.1];
}
@end
```

Comment: As workaround is perfect, but don't resolve apple issue, unfortunately!

Comment: agreed. any idea how to hack the heading delegate? there is no way to create instance of CLHeading and populate it..

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same problem, and searching for a solution, I at least found a workaround: [Testing CoreLocation on iPhone Simulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/802156/testing-corelocation-on-iphone-simulator/3304378#3304378) - It doesn't actually make it work, but in my case I just needed a dummy location anyway.

To make it work, just copy linked code into a header file and link that below your

```
#import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>
```

Like this:

```
#import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>
#import "CoreLocation_Sim.h"
```

Comment: As workaround is perfect, but don't resolve apple issue, unfortunately!

Answer (score 0):

Please see http://pastebin.com/7hvFiXCg for a somewhat souped-up version of the BNR code. It includes CLHeading support, among other adjustments. Enjoy!