# bootstrap_look_up failed (44e) Xcode 4.1, Mac OSX Lion

Tags: iphone, xcode

So I updgraded to Lion on my Mac, which meant I had to get Xcode 4.1.  I had a location based app working and now when I try to find my location, I get this printed to the console which I have no idea what it means:

```
bootstrap_look_up failed (44e)
```

Any thoughts?  Thanks.

Comment: look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6792061/how-to-solve-xcode-4-1-lion-gps-error

Comment: Try to comment out the code line by line and find the problematical line. I got the same console message so I found which line produce this. In one of my view controller init methods I use this line: [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardWillShow:) name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification object:self.view.window]; When I used `nil` instead of `self.view.window` the warning "bootstrap_look_up failed (44e)" disappeared.

Comment: Just wait for Apple, surely they will resolve this issue asap. Otherwise enter a manual location.

Comment: yikes, this problem still hasn't been resolved.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I got the same problem. I didn't find any solution for running applications on the simulator but it seems to work if you install the application on your phone and run it from there.

Comment: Great, thanks for the advice!  I was about to try that, but got busy at home.  Much appreciative!  Please let me know if you do find a fix!   Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
@implementation CLLocationManager (TemporaryHack)

- (void)hackLocationFix
{
  CLLocation *location = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:37.785834    longitude:-122.406417];
   [[self delegate] locationManager:self didUpdateToLocation:location fromLocation:nil];
}

- (void)startUpdatingLocation
{
  [self performSelector:@selector(hackLocationFix) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.1];
 }
```

@end
    SElect all code and paste in AppDelegate.m file before or after 
  @implementation AppDelegate
   @end
    I am not a good teacher if you have any question you may ask again