# Core Location Simulator on Xcode 4.2 Not Working -Any Clues?

Tags: iphone, ios, ios-simulator, core-location, xcode4.2

I checked all the other variants of this, and don't see the answer here. It seems a lot of folks are thinking of Xcode 4.1, and the issues therein.

First of all, I am very happy with Xcode 4.2. It fixes the huge plethora of problems I was having, and, once again, makes the simulator a useful tool. I am very glad for this, because it is a MUCH faster workflow than using the devices.

Now, 4.2 introduces something in their Edit Scheme dialog (Go to the "Run" page, then "Options"). This is called "Core Location [checkbox] Allow Location Simulation". It allows you to pick from a list of pre-defined locations.

This seems to obviate the horrendous hack that I had introduced when I first encountered the issue in Lion.

However, it no workee. I'd like to find out what I am doing wrong. Has anyone gotten this working?

Remember: THIS BEGINS IN 4.2, WHICH JUST CAME OUT YESTERDAY. So the rules from 4.0 and 4.1 don't apply. It is a new capability.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, I created the GPX file as mentioned in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6792061/how-to-solve-xcode-4-1-lion-gps-error/8035567#8035567).

In addition to updating the **Run Scheme** to select the **Allow Location Simulation** option and specifying the **Default Location** as you mentioned, you also need to make sure that your Scheme is set to **iPhone 5.0 Simulator**. This made the trick for me, when I debug my project, the app asks me if I want to allow it to use my current location, and I can see the Debug -> Location menu in the iPhone Simulator.

Comment: Saved me a lot of trouble!

Answer (score 1):

There's a [thread](https://devforums.apple.com/thread/112805) on this bug in the Apple developer forums.   One suggestion is to reset the simulator.

Comment: Thanks! Resetting did not work. However, I see that the IOS5 simulators work just fine. I guess I need to test my CL stuff in the IOS5 sims. Thanks!