# iOS 6 MKMapview - Current Location Is Shown Wrong In Simulator

Tags: ios, ipad, ios5, ios6, ios-simulator

I am using iOS 6 with XCode 4.5.

Trying to create Map based application. In that I have placed Mapview in the XIB and mapped with `IBOutlet` with the corresponding view controller.

I dont have device now, so i am tesing in iOS 6 simulator. The current location is shown as Netherlands, which is irrelevant.

**Tried to solve by:**

1. Editing the schema, by checking and unchecking the option Allow Location Simulation.
2. iOS Simulator Menu -> Debug -> Location -> Changed from none to Apple and other.
3. I have set Show User Location enabled in the Attribute inspector.
4. Also I have given `mapView.showsUserLocation = YES`.

None of the above helped.

Could you please help me in solving this problem.

Thanks,

Comment: If my answer working for you then kindly accept it by clicking on the check mark (left side the answer). It may help others.

Comment: Done thanks SibaPrasadHota

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Simulator is Not having any GPS so it can't show the correct Location. You will find some Predefined Locations by Selecting the Location in your Console.

[image]

[image]

You can get a Nice Project from here for [testing Current Location in simulator](https://github.com/futuretap/FTLocationSimulator).

> FTLocationSimulator allows simulating Core Location in the iPhone
> simulator on the desktop. It sends fake Core Location updates taken
> from a KML file that describes a predefined route.
>
> Besides the simulated Core Location updates, it also updates the blue
> userLocation view on MapKit views. The sample project shows how to
> integrate FTLocationSimulator into an existing app, in this case
> Apple's "Breadcrumb" sample application.

Source : [Testing CoreLocation on iPhone Simulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/802156/testing-corelocation-on-iphone-simulator)

Comment: Oh.. Is it. If you have any link which has this information could you please share which would be useful for many.

Comment: Check my updated Answer. I gave one Link for a sample project named "FTLocationSimulator".